# Adding custom search results that is not in indice on Elastic Site Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-appsearch

I am trying to set up site search for my company's web site. I am using elastic crawler to get data from web site and I can do basic search. (I did not set up, booster or suggesters yet). Our company's Elastic Stack version is 8.3. Here is my question:

I want to add some search result via a file (like csv if it possible), and I need to get first these result when it is a exact match.

For example:

Lets assume that I defined a custom json for search result in local file:

{"cars":"www.company/cars"}

When I search for "cars" It should bring me the result as "www.company/cars" first, than it can bring other related search result from the indice. It have to be exact match, so It should get only indice results when I search for "car". It is not like suggestion, because I want to do this operation on search result.

Do you have any idea- how could I handle this on Elastic?

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. I created another engine by uploding json data (the contex of the .csv file). After that, I created a Meta Engine and I defined two source (one is crawling index, the other one is my json data)  I give extra weigt the field which I want to exact macth. It worked as I aspected.